# Does a lighter-weight alternative to Reachability exist for iOS?

Tags: ios, reachability

The iOS status bar contains an icon that shows you what kind of internet connectivity it thinks you have.  Wi-Fi, 3G, Edge, etc.

Is there an API that will find out what kind of connection the phone thinks it has?

I don't want to use SCNetworkReachability.  I don't want to specify a hostname or address.  I don't want to make any attempt at using the network in any way.  I just want to know what kind of connectivity the device thinks it has.

Does this exist?  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

SCNetworkReachability does not make any attempt at using the network in any way. It does exactly what you want to do and is far from heavyweight. You must however specify a hostname or address - it will then tell you what kind of connection is available to reach that address.  It doesn't actually connect, and it won't tell you if the remote end is available.

Comment: The call can take a long time to return.  I've since switched to using a "zero address", and things seem faster.  I'd like to understand why it can take so long if you specify a hostname.  I assumed that it was performing some sort of routing calculation that required connectivity.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "zero address"?